# Running Javascript at end of loading all Meteor templates load

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor

I have the following template code:

```html
<template name="dashboard">
  <div class="content-container-with-sidebar clearfix">
    <div class="dashboard-container">
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
      <div id=masonry-grid class="masonry-grid clearfix">
        {{> timePieChartCard}}
        {{> expensePieChartCard}}
        {{> HighlightsCard}}
        {{> initializeMasonry}}
      </div>
    {{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'd like to run the initializer for the masonry library after all the templates and their subscriptions/helpers load within the main dashboard template.

Each card has code similar to this:

```html
<template name="HighlightsCard">
  {{#if highlightsExist}}
  <div class="col-md-6 masonry-grid-item">
    <div class="card highlights-card">
    </div>
  </div>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

```js
Template.highlightsCard.onCreated(function() {
  this.autorun(() => {
    this.subscribe('userOwnClientHighlightsData');
  });
});

Template.highlightsCard.helpers({
  highlights() {
    return Highlights.find({}, {
      limit: 4,
      sort: {createdAt: -1}
    }).fetch();
  },
  highlightsExist() {
    return (Highlights.find().count() > 0);
  }
});
```

I currently am setting a session that increases when each onRendered is run within the card templates, but once they all render their contents have still not loaded. I need the class masonry-grid-item to be visible in order for me to initialize masonry.

What's the best way to get a similar result as jquery's $(document).ready() ?

Update: each individual card in the dashboard template has it's own subscription to a different dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to initialize your component after the subscription is complete and after all sub-templates (that also depend on the subscription data) are rendered.

Since I don't know what your JavaScript looks like, here is an example of what you can try.

```
Template.dashboard.onRendered(function() {
  this.isReady = new ReactiveVar(false);

  this.subscribe('subscriptionName', () => {
    this.isReady.set(true);
    Tracker.afterFlush(() => {
      // Initialize component here
    });
  });
});

Template.dashboard.helpers({
  isReady: () => {
    return Template.instance().isReady.get();
  },
});
```

And then use the `isReady` ReactiveVar in your template.  In this case, `isReady`may not be necessary (e.g. you could probably use the `Template.subscriptionsReady` helper), but I like to have explicit control of when to render incase my logic gets more complex in the future. Note, I removed `{{> initializeMasonry}}` because it looked like you were attempting to initialize your component via a helper.

```
<template name="dashboard">
  <div class="content-container-with-sidebar clearfix">
    <div class="dashboard-container">
    {{#if isReady}}
      <div id=masonry-grid class="masonry-grid clearfix">
        {{> timePieChartCard}}
        {{> expensePieChartCard}}
        {{> HighlightsCard}}
      </div>
    {{/if}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The callback to `Tracker.afterFlush` will get executed on the next Blaze render cycle, which will be after your sub-templates are rendered.

Comment: I forgot to mention that each individual card has it's own subscription and helper to check if data is available. I've updated the original post above.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [Tracker.afterFlush](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-afterFlush)

> Schedules a function to be called during the next flush

For example:

```
Template.dashboard.onRendered(()=>{
  Tracker.afterFlush(()=>{
    ...your code here
  });
});
```